# Как можно получить доступ к предыдущему дочернему объекту у другого дочернего объекта с одним родителем в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня в игре случайно генерируются комнаты и когда ты открываешь дверь в другую комнату происходит шанс появления монстра который должен появится в трансформ точке предыдущей комнаты и пройти до конца той которую открыли как можно это осуществить? (Все комнаты при появлении относятся к одному родительскому объекту).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Transform.GetChild(int index)
```

index это, соответственно, номер дочернего элемента. Если у тебя монстр всегда один, то просто ставь `0`